--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED while some migration Java 8 to Java 17
i have an old library in my project : Orika. I use the lastest version of this library.
My project is developped  spring boot 3 and tomcat is embed.
but to launch with eeclipse my project i must use --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED (VM Arguments with Eclipse)
How can i do turn on a Server? how can i config my server?
thank for your help

Does this answer your question? How can I specify --add-opens from a project level and make sure it is taken into account whatever the means to run my app?

Merci pour ce lien. Je l’avais trouvé mais je n’arrivais pas à l’appliquer. Mon projet n’a pas de manifest. C’est bizarre. Et je génère un war mais je ne pense pas que ça change.

Aucun projet n'a de manifest qu'un développeur aurait créé à la main. C'est maven qui s'occupe tout seul d'en créer un, si tu utilises les commandes proposées. En général, il se planque toujours un MANIFEST.MF quelque-part, dans ce que génère maven, que ce soit dans un jar fat, un war ou un ear.

Donc si j’applique ta configuration de l’autre poste avec un war cela change t’il quelques choses? Je fait exactement ce que tu as mis dans le pom.xml et je fais Maven install. Ça devrait générer le bon manifest?

Ça me rassure que tu me dit que ça fonctionne. Je vais creuser cette piste. Donc si je lance dans éclipse ça devrait tourner sans que j’ai besoin de rajouter Ade-opens dans com argumentss


org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-war-plugin



java.base/sun.util.calendar java.base/java.util




je n'arrive pas à générer de manifest
